# Cannot import anything from PyQt5

Tags: python, windows, installation, pyqt5

I've successfully installed Python 3.5.1 and PyQt5. But as soon as I try to import anything from PyQt5, it fails like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
File "stdn", line 1, in "module"
ImportError: Dll load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've checked my PATH and everything is OK: I have both D:\Python3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5 and D:\Python3\Lib\site-packages.

Python and PyQt5 are both 64-bit versions.
Path Printscreen:
[This is a printscreen of my Environment variable Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0bva.jpg)

Comment: Somethings wrong. Hard to say what exactly. We don't know what you installed, or how you installed it. Perhaps you are missing a runtime dependency. We can only guess.

Comment: What **exactly** is your PATH?

Comment: I've just connected a printscreen of my Path below my question description. 
Since I've got stuck with it with my new notebook, first i've uninstalled all previous Pythons (2.7 and 3.5.1), and than installed Puthon again and PyQT5.exe installer in the same as Python directory.

Could it be anything except the Path? Any guess? Thanks.